# Center menu items within background image

Tags: css, header

I've looked at the other posts regarding this topic and after many hours of trial and error I think it's time to ask the question so I continue creating the site.

I have a header whose width is 100% of the browser and includes a logo in the top left and a navigation menu to the right, with a textured background image that the menu items should be centered within.  I'm close but the extra margin to the left of the first menu item is bothering me and I'd like to center all of the items within the background image (edit: I don't have permission to post the image)

Here's my html:

```
<div class="header">

    <div id="logo" class="grid_4">
      <img src="img/mainlogo-box-texture.png" alt="Hibachi Hero">
    </div>

    <div class="grid_6 omega">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="menu.html">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.header { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 175px;
  background: #D35640;
}   

ul.menu {
  background: url('img/navtexture5.png') no-repeat;
  margin-top: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}

ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin: 10px 30px 10px 5px;
}

ul.menu li a {
  color: #BABABA;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
  color: #d35640;
  background: #efec69;
}
```

Would really appreciate any insight.  Thanks!